# nav links do not hide when ul is at 0%

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to create a side nav with HTML, CSS, and Javascript. I was able to create the function in order to open and close the navigation. The issue I am running into which I did not notice until I added the background image is that the links still pop out even though the navigation is closed. I tried display: none; on both the li and links. The results are that no links appear and if I try visibility only the Home link appears. here is my code

```
<nav>
            <p class="brand">DreamJob</p>
        
        <div class="burger">
            <div class="line"></div>
        </div>
        <ul class="ul-one">
            <li class="li-one"><a href="#" class="links-one">Home</a></li>
            <li class="li-one"><a href="#" class="links-one">About</a></li>
            <li class="li-one"><a href="#" class="links-one">Contact</a></li>
            <li class="li-one"><a href="#" class="links-one">Feedback</a></li>
            <li class="li-one"><a href="#" class="links-one">Sign up</a></li>
            <li class="li-one"><a href="#" class="links-one">Sign in</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>

nav .ul-one {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 90px;
  background-color: #111;
  width: 0;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  transition: 0.5s ease-in-out;
}

nav .ul-one .li-one {
  margin: 10px 0px 10px 0px;
  z-index: 200;
}

nav .ul-one .li-one .links-one {
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-family: karma;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: none;
}

function nav () {
    let burger = document.querySelector(".burger");
    let ul = document.querySelector("ul-one");
    let links = document.querySelector(".links-one");
    let openNav = false;
    burger.addEventListener("click", ()  =>  {
if (!openNav) {
   document.querySelector(".ul-one").style.width = "40%";
   document.querySelector(".links-one").style.display ="block";
   openNav = true;
}else {
    document.querySelector(".ul-one").style.width = "0";
    document.querySelector(".links-one").style.display ="none";
    openNav = false;
}
    });
}
nav();
```

Answer (score 0):

your problem is with the querySelector function.
according to https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector
querySelector returns first element that matched with the provided selector not all of them.

you have to use querySelectorAll or getElementsByClassName and change style for every element in elements list.